# Accessing logs folder of running docker container

Tags: docker

Suppose my application generate logs in a folder /app/logs/ . For convenience multiple log files are generated (based on different runtime contexts) for better monitoring. If I containerize my application using Docker, how can I access my logs generated at runtime in logs folder?

My application doesn't have a nohup type of logging and certainly

```
docker logs -f <container-id>
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) will only show the stderr and stdout from the process you are running.

Containers work well with a centralised logging system as it fits with their ephemeral/scalable design.  Use [syslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/), [loggly](https://www.loggly.com/), [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/), [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) etc to [push your docker logs over the network to a server](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/). Access all your app and context logs in one location.

If that seems like too much...

You can access the logs directly from the host

```
docker exec <container-id> cat /apps/logs/context.log
```

You can log to a shared data volume

```
docker volume create logs
docker run -v logs:/apps/logs <image>
```

You can log to a host directory

```
docker run -v /apps/logs:/apps/logs <image>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Every method was quite apt and self explanatory.

Comment: I have few questions now. Does logging to shared data volume or directly on host directory involves docker exec commands. Because in that case, there are memory leak possibilities. In past it led to my machine in a complete locked up/ frozen state and required manual restart of machine.

Comment: The logging itself would be done by the process you `run`, `exec` shouldn't be involved in logging.  You can access the shared and host volumes without using `exec`.  There are ways to access data in a container without `exec` if needed, `cp` for example.